# Android: How do you display Webview inside Tabview?

Tags: android, webview

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/myWebView"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.webview);
  WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);  
  webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
 }
```

tabview xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Tabview java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabview);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent; // Reusable Intent for each tab


        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, WebActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("webview")
                .setIndicator("webview", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.info))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

                // add other tabs

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
```

This will launch a webView in full screen.

Is it possible to display webview inside the tabview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the answer here: http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation

By default WebView launches the browser everytime you visit a new URL, so what happens is, it launches the browser.

To avoid this happening everytime you click something etc, you need to add a WebViewClient to your WebView:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

If you need to peform some particular action when a user clicks a link, implement your own WebViewClient:

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        boolean result = false;

        /* ... */
        // Return false to proceed loading page, true to interrupt loading

        return result;
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```